# How to use UIPanGestureRecognizer to move 2 or more UIImageViews

Tags: ios, uiimageview, move, pan, uipangesturerecognizer

This site has been very helpful when it comes to explaining how to use UIPanGestureRecognizer to move a UIImageView, but I have a program where I need to move (i.e., pan) more than one UIImageView and for the life of me I can't find an example of how to do that.

I understand that a UIPanGestureRecognizer is assigned to a UIView, but instead of being able to pan any UIImageView within the UIView, I only know the code to pan only one UIImageView with the UIView as seen in the code below.

Here is the code I've used.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[_canvas addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

[super viewDidLoad]; }


-(void)move:(id)sender {
CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:_canvas];

if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    _firstX = [photoImage center].x;
    _firstY = [photoImage center].y;
}

translatedPoint = CGPointMake(_firstX+translatedPoint.x, _firstY+translatedPoint.y);
[photoImage setCenter:translatedPoint]; }
```

I can pan a UIImageView called photoImage, but  know what the code would look like to pan more than one UIImageView.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the gesture recognizer to all of your images instead of the _canvas.
And also set userInteractionEnabled to YES for these views

```
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Yadyn. Here's the modified code, but only the photoImage2 UIImageView will pan. 


 - (void)viewDidLoad {

...

[photoImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[photoImage2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[photoImage addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
[photoImage2 addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
... }

-(void)move:(id)sender {
...
    _firstX = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender locationInView:self.view].x;
    _firstY = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender locationInView:self.view].y;
}

...

[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view].center = translatedPoint; }

Comment: UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender;
UIView *selectedView = [recognizer view];
 
CGPoint point = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
 
if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)  {
 firstX = selectedView.center.x;
 firstY = selectedView.center.y;
}
 
point = CGPointMake(firstX+point.x, firstY+point.y);
[selectedView setCenter:point];
 
if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)  {
 [selectedView setCenter:point];
}

I use this code and it works fine for me no matter how many views are there

Answer (score 0):

I have just written an app for someone that does that exact action. Basically, all you have to do is create the image view(s), and insert them into a NSArray, as such:

```
NSArray *imageViews = @[imageView, imageView2];
```

Then, just go through each one using a for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageViews.count; i++) {
     [imageViews[i] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
     [imageViews[i] addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
}
```

That is all that is required to make this action work. Just make sure the above code is in your viewDidLoad method because that's where you create your panGesture.

Hope this helps!